# Picture frame hung by posts in restriction positions

Tags: forces, free-body-diagram, torque

Suppose you have a picture frame (or mirror) and it is held up by a string that goes around two posts which are at coordinates $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$. The corners of the frame are at $(0,0)$ and $(w,0)$.

When is this system in equilibrium? (Assume no friction between the string and the posts.)

Is the answer that the tensions between $(0,0)-(x_1,y_1)$ and between $(x_2,y_2)-(w,0)$ have to be the same? Is the tension in the string equal throughout its length?

This problem was posed by a friend who wanted to place the posts into wall studs (thus being restricted in position) and also wanted to specify exactly where the edges of the frame would be.

[image]